Re-order Bar Chart (not decsending/ascending order or weekday/month)
I need to create a bar plot that has the Y axis in a particular order. I need the Y axis to be ordered small, medium, unlimited. When I run the code it keeps ordering it medium, small, unlimited.
All of the resources online are for ordering the Y axis by decsending/ascending order or weekday/month.

SummarypH <- summarySE(df, measurevar ="pH_H", 
                       groupvars=c("pit_size"), na.rm = TRUE)

 arrange(pit_size) %>%
+   mutate(pit_size = factor(pit_size, levels= c("small","medium", "unlimited"))

p<-ggplot(SummarypH, aes(x=pit_size, y=pH_H)) + 
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity", fill="darkgreen") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=pH_H-se, ymax=pH_H+se),
                width=.2,               # Width of the error bars
                position=position_dodge(.9)) + ylab("pH") +
  xlab("Soil Area")  + theme_bw()
p


I have tried the re-order function and createing a factor but nothing is working.

please use dput(df) to share the data for your example, before someone can help you solve the problem

To sort that categoricals for a bar chart, make the variable (pit_size) a factor with the levels in the order in which you want them to appear.
 SummarypH$pit_size <- factor(SummarypH$pit_size, levels = c("small", "medium", "unlimited"))

for example:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggiraphExtra)

df <- data.frame(pH_H = runif(30, 4, 8),
                 pit_size = sample(c("small", "medium", "unlimited"), 30, replace = TRUE))

SummarypH <- summarySE(
  df,
  measurevar = "pH_H",
  groupvars = c("pit_size"),
  na.rm = TRUE
)

SummarypH$pit_size <- factor(SummarypH$pit_size, levels = c("small", "medium", "unlimited"))

ggplot(SummarypH, aes(x = pit_size, y = pH_H)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(),
           stat = "identity",
           fill = "darkgreen") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = pH_H - se, ymax = pH_H + se),
                width = .2,
                position = position_dodge(.9)) +
  ylab("pH") +
  xlab("Soil Area")  +
  theme_bw()

